# How to use AWS WAF to block requests whose "user-agent" header is not "Java/1.8"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I want to use AWS WAF to block the requests whose `user-agent` header is not `Java/1.8`.

How can I achieve this goal?

The Regex pattern of WAF doesn't support `Arbitrary zero-width assertions`.

So I can't use [lookahead and lookbehind regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in WAF.

I originally want to use `^((?!Java\/1.8).)*$` to block the requests whose `user-agent` header is not `Java/1.8`.

The match type of a statement in a rule builder doesn't provide `Not equal to string`.

[image]

So I really cannot figure out a way to achieve the goal I want.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that, you need to change the `Default web ACL action for requests that don't match any rules` to `Block`, and then add your rule that allows access if `user-agent` match or contains what you want.

You can do that by accessing the Rules tab of your WAF and scrolling down to this part:
[image]